# Unable to get message() String from localization table in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am using [Localizations (messages) plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/localizations) to pull i18n definitions from the database rather than from the standard properties files in the i18n folder.

I am trying to use Localization plugin into my Service.groovy file. I am doing like this ..

```
import org.grails.plugins.localization.*
// some code.....
def body = message(code: "goal.auto.email.alert")  
log.info("body : "+body)
```

When I check log, my body is showing null. I already added record with same code name into my Localization table. But it is not getting String message from the table. I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my experience, I think `message(code: "goal.auto.email.alert")` will not work in Service. So I did this by using sql query ..

```
def body = sql.rows("SELECT TEXT FROM Localization WHERE CODE='goal.auto.email.alert'") 
    body = body.text[0]
```

And now it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
class FirstService {

def messageSource

  def test() {
    ...
    def msg = messageSource.getMessage('localization.cache.hits', null, Locale.US)
    ...
  }
}
```

See the [blog](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/accessing-messages-propertiesi18n-in-grails-services/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this blog showing method to read messages from messages.properties. I don't want to use message.properties file to get String. I already have Localization table into my database. I want to get message from that table only.

Comment: I have create a test application and tested it with localization plugin using h2 database and it is working fine.

Comment: I put that code into my service like this ..
messageSource.getMessage('goal.auto.email.alert', null, Locale.US) where `goal.auto.email.alert` is defined into my localization table but its not working.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Actually i have written my backend job where i am using Service to send mail. For mail body i am using localization plugin to get message body from the table.

Comment: I am not getting error, but it is now not printing my body message in log

Comment: this is my localization table -- `CREATE TABLE `localization` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `relevance` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`,`loc`),
  KEY `localizations_idx` (`code`,`loc`)
)`

Comment: I have tried from this way also `Localization.findByCode("goal.auto.email.alert")?.text` but no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38600/discussion-between-user1690588-and-shreshtt-bhatt)